# does undetected-chromedriver have a JS/npm version to use for cloudflare detecting selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cloudflare, undetected-chromedriver

Trying to run a bot once daily to fill out a short form and cloud flare is preventing my submission with human verification. Pretty sure using undetected-chromedriver will solve issue but I am looking for a JS solution.

[image]

May build out solution in python to use https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/, but I am curious about JavaScript solutions.

Comment: The js equivalent would be either puppeteer + puppeteer-extra-stealth or possibly fake-browser.

Comment: @pguardiario i am using puppeteer + puppeteer-extra-stealth but it cannot pass clouadfare now. Any suggest?

Comment: You might have to solve the captcha with 2captcha or similar